# How can I manually progress an iterator variable in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I would like to know how to manually progress an iterator variable in Python3. In C, for example, if during a `for` loop such as:

`for( int i = 0, k = 10; i < k; ++i)`, I could skip loop iterations when `i == {2,3,4}` by simply setting `i` from within the loop body like this: `if(i == 1) i = 5;`

However, when I do something like this from within a `for in` loop in Python3, the `for in` loop actually enforces that I cannot do this - it mutates `i` and sets it to the next sequential number regardless of what I did to the iterator variable in the loop body.

For example in the `Python3` code below, I am trying to progress `i` to the position of `j` such that I can skip `i` to the end of the group of spaces once the algorithm has detected a group of spaces:

```
testString = "This is a   testzstring"
# find length and end of each space group
spacePositionsAndLengths = {}
j = 0
length = len(testString)
for i in range(length):
    if testString[i] == " ":
        j = i # mark beginning of spaces
        while j < length and testString[j] == " ":
            j += 1
        # j-1 is now the last space. Alternatively, j is at first non-space
        lengthOfSpaces = j-i
        print(f"i: {i}\t lengthOfSpaces: {lengthOfSpaces}")
        spacePositionsAndLengths[i] = lengthOfSpaces
        i = j # remember, at this point j is at first non-space

print(testString)
```

That algorithm prints this output when run with:

```
i: 4     lengthOfSpaces: 1
i: 7     lengthOfSpaces: 1
i: 9     lengthOfSpaces: 3
i: 10    lengthOfSpaces: 2
i: 11    lengthOfSpaces: 1
This is a   testzstring
```

This is decent, but what I want is it to print this:

```
i: 4     lengthOfSpaces: 1
i: 7     lengthOfSpaces: 1
i: 9     lengthOfSpaces: 3
This is a   testzstring
```

I do not want the redundant 3..2..1 "countdown" style space counting.

*Note: I am not building a production application; I am working on algorithms and the instructions require me to NOT use many of the builtin string methods. I note this because I expect comments saying "Why don't you just use X, Y, or Z builtin function and be done with this whole thing in 1 line??"*

Comment: You are not looking for the `continue` statement?

Comment: I suggest you use `while` instead of `for`. Python's `while` is a closer analogue of C's `for` and you then have full control of the index variable.

Comment: The for loop doesn't modify the value referred to by the variable `i`, it sets it based on an iterator object which is created when you enter the loop. Changing `i` after the fact doesn't change the iterator object or what the next value set is. The C example you have is incrementing `i` instead of setting it anew each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

To manually progress the iterator, you need access to it. You can explicitly create the iterator yourself and then both give it to the `for` statement and treat it yourself as you wish. Example:

```
irange = iter(range(10))
for i in irange:
    print(i)
    next(irange)
```

Output:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Though in your example, a `while` loop might be better.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a while loop so that you can have your own iterator that you can mutate. It may look something like.

```
j = 0
i = 0
length = len(testString)
while i < length:
    if testString[i] == " ":
        j = i # mark beginning of spaces
        while j < length and testString[j] == " ":
            j += 1
        # j-1 is now the last space. Alternatively, j is at first non-space
        lengthOfSpaces = j-i
        print(f"i: {i}\t lengthOfSpaces: {lengthOfSpaces}")
        spacePositionsAndLengths[i] = lengthOfSpaces
        i = j # remember, at this point j is at first non-space
     i += 1
```

Comment: Where can I find the definition of "iterator" that says you're using one? And it can be done without a while loop, so "need" is wrong.

Comment: @KellyBundy While you're technically correct, I don't think this answer is unclear or incorrect, it's just a bit imprecise in language.

Comment: @CJR Well, it's a Python question asking about iterators. There's no iterator here, at least not in Python's sense of the word (and I skimmed Wikipedia's article as well, which explicitly distinguishes it from indexing such as this).

Comment: @KellyBundy I understand why don't like the terminology. But I explicitly stated that he creates his own iterator and not an iterator in the python sense.